# PySpark : how to split data without randomnize

Tags: pyspark, training-data

there are function that can randomize spilt data

```
trainingRDD, validationRDD, testRDD = RDD.randomSplit([6, 2, 2], seed=0L)
```

I'm curious if there a way that we generate data the same partition ( train 60 / valid 20 / test 20 ) but  **without randommize** ( let's just say use the current data to split first 60 = train, next 20 =valid and last 20  are for test data)

is there a possible way to split data similar way to split but not randomize?

Answer (score 2):

The basic issue here is that unless you have an index column in your data, there is no concept of "first rows" and "next rows" in your RDD, it's just an unordered set. If you have an integer index column you could do something like this:

```
train = RDD.filter(lambda r: r['index'] % 5 <= 3)
validation = RDD.filter(lambda r: r['index'] % 5 == 4)
test = RDD.filter(lambda r: r['index'] % 5 == 5)
```